# Java string split on string "},"

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String that i need to split on the expression "},"
I tried to do simply:

```
String[] result = myString.split("},");
```

but it didn't work, then i tried to do:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("},");
String[] result = p.split(myString);
```

And I got a PatternSyntaxException

Any advice please?
Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it again after escaping `{` character that is already a part of [Java regex pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
String[] result = myString.split("\\},");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\},");
String[] result = p.split(myString);
```

---

It's working without escaping character `}` as well. What is your input string?

Sample code:

```
String myString = "{abc},{lmn},{xyz}";

System.out.println(myString.split("},").length); // 3

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("},");
String[] result = p.split(myString);
System.out.println(result.length); // 3
```

Test your regex on [DEBUGGEX - Online visual regex tester](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CD9m1DxUrAqIbff2)

Comment: Hi, my string is in the following link: http://praytime.info/getprayertimes.php?lat=31%C2%B047%E2%80%B2N&lon=35%C2%B013%E2%80%B2E&gmt=+2&m=6&y=2014&school=0

Comment: Is it all in single line?

Comment: Yes, the string has no "\n" at all

Comment: It gives me array length 30 and that's expected.

Comment: It's a JSON string and you can convert it into JAVA POJO object easily using Gson and Json.

Comment: Thanks, Your suggestion to escape the character just worked fine. I don't know why it's needed, but it just worked, Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link or an example for Gson?

Comment: Sure Find it [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) and [here](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/). Read my posts on [Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a3218114%20[gson]) for more samples